# Azure SQL Login Failed > PW Reset > Login Success > Later > Error Again

Tags: sql-server, azure

This is the scenario:

1. **Login to SQL Database (failed)**
2. Tried again (failed)
3. Not sure what happen, tried to troubleshoot (still failed)
4. Password Reset (using same password - successful)
5. **Login to SQL Database (successful)**
6. After few minutes inactivity, tried to do something on DB
7. Error prompted (connection failed)
8. So I disconnected, and login again (failed)
9. **BACK TO STEP 1**

I am new to Microsoft Azure and Azure SQL, so I am not sure what is happening.

Badly need help!

Other details:

- Azure SQL Database
- Single Database
- Pay-As-You-Go Subscription
- Basic Pricing Tier

Tried login using MSSQL Studio, EMS SQL Manager, & Azure Query Editor (All failed)

Only fix is a quick Password Reset, but it sort of expires very quick.
Passwords seems corrupted after a few minutes, so when I do a reset using same password, it works again.

Comment: Can you show us the error message? And did you login with Server Admin?

Comment: I am using the server admin account. Login failed for user (Error 18456) - just a typical invalid credentials error. Right after password reset, any new login is successful. But after an undetermined number of minutes, any login fails again with same error even in Azure's built-in query editor.

The only thing I could do for now is to do a password reset everytime using the old password so I don't have to update the connection strings on my app.

BADLY NEED HELP! #SOS

Comment: Is it possible that your account gets locked out? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/howto-password-smart-lockout OR https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/password-policy?view=sql-server-2017